# 2.5 template/css issues: article links not working in Chrome, link colors locked globally to white and email cloaking

Tags: php, joomla-2.5, javascript, css

I'm a Joomla, CSS and php newbie.  I was tasked with creating a site for the school I just started working for based on its already hacked-up Joomla 2.5 template. I hacked it some more to get the general required layout, but now have some frustrating bugs I can't fix.  I'm not allowed to go to a Joomla 3 template -- that's out of my hands.

Here is the site:
http://www.novaschool.org/index.php/nova-home

Here are the issues:

1. I cannot get links to work in the article, such as the blue "value proposition" image under that main splash graphic.  It should be like clicking the "About Nova" left menu item, but you can't even see a link on Chrome. It works in IE 9 on my computer.  I even put in a basic  tag, and Chrome won't recognize it.
2. I got the text links white for the menu, but no matter how/where I seem to try making the link colors dark for the article and that gray side news module, I can't get them to be any other color than white.
3. I am getting the dreaded "you need javascript" to see the text mailto links.  Of course, they are white right now, so you can't see them.  I've tried to deal with the cloaking, but to no avail.  Must be doing it wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.  Please understand that I am a novice, so I need the code syntax as well as specific location to paste it in.

Comment: Thanks y'all. That did it! I should explain that I started the position of Advancement Director at the school in August. I inherited a Joomla-based site and a template that had been heavily modified by a contractor. There are a lot of politics involved with the site, but I have been tasked with creating this new site in a timeframe that is rather short by non-profit standards. I didn't have the ability to move away from Joomla, or I would have. I was able to code a mockup of the front page in five minutes with Notepad and HTML, but it took weeks to do it in Joomla with the lack of experience w

Comment: Welcome to Joomla SE. I'm glad you solved your problems. Please note that Stack Exchange is not a forum, it's a Q&A site with concrete questions and (usually) concrete answers. Although it's usually encoraged to answer your own questions, this "answer" does not respond any questions.
The best way to say thanks on SE is to upvote the answers you liked, and accept one of the questions if it solved your problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for more details.

Comment: Sorry. I gave -1 for the same reasons as stated above. Glad you found the site helpful though :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: This question was already asked, and answered, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26051476/modified-joomla-template-now-no-main-area-links-work-in-chrome-but-work-fine-in/26055677#26055677 Posting the same question over and over again, and never acknowledging the answers, simply wastes everyones time.

Answer (score 2):

1. This is because your sidebar is overlapping the whole content area as it's width has been set to `90%`. Go to line *180* of your **main.css** file and change the width to `18%`
2. The white links on the right sidebar are coming from line *104* of your **template.css** file. Somewhere in this file, simply add in `#right a { color: #000; }` which will target all links on the right sidebar.
3. I don't see any mailto links so no idea what the issue is here.

Before getting the site live, I would strongly suggest you do some research for HTML and CSS. The template structure is written rather badly, which is fine as I understand that you're new to this

Not sure why you're using Joomla for such a small site, but I rest my case about hacking into core files. Never a good idea, never, ever, ever **ever**.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your issue **#3**:
Joomla has a built-in email cloaking system. It works automatically, but you can turn it off by disabling the "Content - Email Cloaking" plugin (Extensions -> Plugin Manager).

I think in your case it has nothing to do with the plugin, but rather an error in the email link format. You should take a look at the source code of your article, it looks like your email link has a `<span id="` code inside (the `"` creates a conflict in your code). Your HTML output looks like this:

```
<a style="color: #3c87de; text-decoration: none;" href="mailto:<span id=" cloak36205"="">This email address is being protected from spambots. You need JavaScript enabled to view it.</a>
```

Right-click your `mailto:` link and make sure it's correctly formatted (`<a href="mailto:your@email.com">your@email.com</a>`), or click the "Source Code" (<kbd>**<>**</kbd>) button in the Tiny MCE editor toolbar.